# Function changes reference without purpose

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a code:

```
Node** ptrlow = ReturnLowest(root); ///pointer po pointer pointing lowest
//DeleteNode(ptrlow);
Test(ptrlow);
```

I think that what this code does is not important, the important thing is that, when I realised that function DeleteNode(Node** &node) changes a value of ptrlow without any purpose, I created the function called Test:

```
void Test(Node** &node)
{
    return;
}
```

That is really the whole function, it does nothing more, yet it changes the value of ptrlow, which is passed to that function.

Before entering the Test function:
[link to screen from visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnw7E.png)
After entering:
[link to screen from visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIHS3.png)
One step more in debugger, a node changes:
[link to screen from visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzfgD.png)

Can someone explain to me how is that possible? I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

On the last picture, the debugger is out of the scope of the function, therefore the arguments passed should have already been discarded (`node` doesn't exist anymore).

The value of `Node** ptrlow` remains the same, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know it should remain the same, but look, it really changes :
[Compare this screen with the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMoOB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting some lines of code, DeleteNode function, had a lot of them.

[DeleteNode function at the beggining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKHPu.png)

[DeleteNode function one step further; node changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVx8Y.png)